# Best way to redirect site in subdirectory to root?

Tags: htaccess, rewrite-rules

I have a WP 4.0 site that has been installed at:

```
mydomain.com/site
```

It's been there for many years, so there are lots of links from around the web pointing to it.

As part of an overhaul I am doing, I would like the wordpress site to be accessible at the root URI:  mydomain.com (and www.mydomain.com), without "/site" needing to be on there.

I found articles that told me about copying the index.php and .htaccess to the root, and changing the site URI in the wordpress settings. But the instructions I've come across always seem incomplete, as they seem to assume it's a new site with no existing links to deal with in order to avoid lots of 404 errors.

So the issue I now have is that the old links generate 404 errors (because they have "/site/" in them. Images also fail to display, as they are obviously stored in the DB with "/site/" in their URI.

I have been trying to figure out a failsafe way to use .htaccess rewrite rules to redirect everything (except, wp-admin, I suppose?) from /site to /

In case it's helpful, my existing permalink structure is 
`mydomain.com/site/%postname%-%post_id%/`

Any suggestions on the best way to go about this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you plan to keep the permalink structure that way? Are you only moving WordPress or also hosts – do you stick with Apache?

Comment: Yes, permalink structure will stay the same, although without the "/site/" in front of it. Same host, etc. Just wanting to drop the "/site/" out of the picture for the end user. I have other apps installed in various other subdirectories, so it is important that they don't get redirect (for instance, mydomain.com/owl/ needs to work as per normal.

Comment: I am not sure if this is 100% right (probably not), but something along the lines of `RewriteRule ^site/ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]` in your .htaccess should work. All requests containing `site/` will be redirected to the same URL without `site` in it – permanently, without considering case and without following any other rules after that.

Comment: @Sven: Thanks. I seem to be having an issue getting that to work. I am doing this on a local test server, before trying on the live one. Should I put that RewriteRule into the .htaccess of `/site/` or the root, or both? If either case, is it necessary to have RewriteBase, and if so, should that be `/` or `/site/`? Is there a simple way to test if mod_rewrite is even firing?

Comment: I tested your rewrite rule at http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/, and it seems to behave as it should. But no joy on the test server or live site. Am going to ask the host if there is something I am overlooking.

Comment: That should go into the .htaccess file in the root, `RewriteBase /`. I am not sure how to test for mod_rewrite – as longs as it's installed and there is `RewriteEngine on` before any rewrite statements, it should work. If there is something really wrong, you'll get an Internal Server Error 500.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I managed to get this to work was with the following in the `.htaccess` of the */site/* directory:

```
RewriteBase \
RedirectMatch 301 ^/site/$ /$1
RedirectMatch 301 ^/site/(?!wp-admin/|wp-content/|wp-includes/)(.*)$ /$1
```

Whilst I am aware that `RewriteRule ^site/ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]` should have worked, and that `RewriteRule ^site/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]` should have also worked (according to various articles I read), I had no luck with these (and no server error).

My host is Hostgator.com - in case this result is relevant to their particular configuration (which I doubt).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by moving the `index.php` to the root open up the index file change the following:

```
/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/site/wp-blog-header.php' )
```

Replace site with the folder. Then in the admin under settings - general change the site URL and remove the folder *www.website.co.uk/site* will be *www.website.co.uk*

Then save the site will work normally though you will need to delete the `.htaccess` and resave the permalinks to make sure it follows the new structure.

Comment: Thanks Phoenix. I suspect you misunderstood my questions. I apologise if it was not clear enough. Changing the site location in the way you have suggested, was what I'd done already. My issue was that this method does not take existing links (and subsequent 404 errors) into account. I needed a way to deal with 400+ posts suddenly having a 404 error. See my answer below for how I resolved that. Cheers...

Comment: That 404 will only happen if you used the old .htacess if you refresh it when you enter www.website.com/sites/page2 it would redirect to www.website.com/page2 automatically as really you havent moved the site just rewriting the url..